# Detecting the table of an onChanged() event with multiple JTable in a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtabbedpane

I'm currently using a `JFrame` to hold a `JTabbedPane` that contains multiple tables. In my class that `extends JFrame` and `implements TableModelListener`, I have an `onChanged()` method that takes a `TableModelEvent` as an argument. I can successfully obtain data from the event on the table that the event was fired from, but I can't determine which table it was.

From what I understand, this is not the way to do what I intend to do. I believe that I may need to write a custom `TableModelListener` or `JTable` and implement the `onChanged()` method there.

What do I need to do to determine which `JTable` was changed in the `JTabbedPane`? I'll need to find the table and the row that was modified.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the -1, particularly given the answers that were given and that there weren't existing questions about the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TableModelListener` and `TableModelEvent` won't provide information about the `JTable` that the model is associated with, as the model may be shared by multiple tables, in theory.

Getting the row is matter of getting the row from the event, which comes from the `firstRow` and `lastRow` properties.  Once you can establish which table the model belongs to you, you can determine the view row by using [`JTable#convertRowIndexToView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView%28int%29)

To find the `JTable` you have, at least, two basic solutions

### You Could...

Ask each table, stored in each `JTabbedPane` for their model and compare it with the model that generated the table model event

### You Could...

Maintain some kind of look up between the `TableModel` and the `JTable` or `JTabbedPane`, depending on what it's you are ultimately after

This could be achieved by using `Map` of some kind, keyed to the `TableModel`

Comment: Gotcha; If I compare each JTable's model with the model that fired the event, isn't it possible that they're sharing the same model and that they'd all return true if compared?

Comment: @user3563124 Yep, that's a risk, but in that case, every table would have changed.  The model row will be the same, by the view row might be different depending on how the table is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe that I may need to write a custom TableModelListener...

Check out the [Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/).

It is very similar to a TableModelListener, but you do need to specify the JTable when creating the `TableCellListener`, so you do have access to the table when a value is changed.