# TableModelListener, tableChanged() event on multiple JTable

Tags: java, swing, model, jtable

I have problems with JTables and JTabbedPane

I have a jtable "jtable1" in the main panel of my JFrame
I have a seconde JTable "jtable2" inside a JTabbedPane (contain in main panel also) of my JFrame.

In My JFrame constructor:

```
jatble1.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
jtable2.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
```

My JFrame Implements TableModelListener and redefine tableChanged method

```
@Override

public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) , only work for jtable1.
```

I want to make change from my jtable2 (inside JTabbedPaned) on a boolean column value and then update jtable1 outside JTabbedPane.

How to do it ?

Begining of answer:

> [Detecting the table of an onChanged() event with multiple JTable in a
>   JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463097/detecting-the-table-of-an-onchanged-event-with-multiple-jtable-in-a-jtabbedpan/46647429#46647429) but @user3563124 and @MadProgrammer didn't provide
>   implementation.

How @user3563124 implements his onChanged() methode ? So it's will help me.

Thank you for your help.

**EDITED:**

[image]

```
public class JTableInteraction extends javax.swing.JFrame implements TableModelListener{

// Model of the JTable which is in JFrame
private StudentAbsenceModel studentAbsenceModel; 

// Model of the JTable which is in JTabbedPane
private StudentListModel studentListModel;

/**
 * Creates new form JTableInteraction
 */
public JTableInteraction() {
    initComponents();

    studentAbsenceModel = new StudentAbsenceModel();
    studentListModel = new StudentListModel();

    jtableAbsence.setModel(studentAbsenceModel);
    jtableListe.setModel(studentListModel);

    // Add TableModelListener to the JTable
    jtableAbsence.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);

    // from jtabbedpane
    jtableListe.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);

}

@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Model used : " + e.getClass());
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jtableAbsence = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jtableListe = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jXSearchField1 = new org.jdesktop.swingx.JXSearchField();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Absence management");

    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jtableListe);

    jXSearchField1.setName(""); // NOI18N
    jXSearchField1.setPrompt("Write a search criteria");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JTableInteraction().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
private org.jdesktop.swingx.JXSearchField jXSearchField1;
private javax.swing.JTable jtableAbsence;
private javax.swing.JTable jtableListe;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

So I want if I checked/Unchecked Absent in the second JTable (jtableListe inside jtabbedPane) automticalely the first JTable (jtableAbsence in JFrame JTableInteraction) to be updated and vice versa.

How to do it ?

**Note: for this method**

```
@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Model used : " + e.getClass());
}

Result out:

Model used: com.test.tablemodels.StudentAbsenceModel
```

**com.test.tablemodels.StudentListModel** *never display* even I checked/unchecked "absent" column of jtableListe  from JTabbedPane.

So this method doesn't work for jtableListe event to jtableAbsence only for  jtableAbsence event to jtableListe (note that the 2 table models have TableModelListerner as Listener).

Need help, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you'll need two listeners or one listener that sees both models. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: I edited my question to include details, it's more clear now i think ! so how to use listeners ? thanks

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in your fragment; you might try isolating the problem in a more focused [mcve] with just two tables and without the complications of the IDE and `swingx`.

Comment: Even the illustration on the picture ? The fragment is so clear, JTableInteraction  class extends JFrame and implements TableModelListener; Two privates variables which represent models of jtables initialized in the constructeur and then I added the TableModelListener to the models of the table in the constructor and implement tableChanged() method. What is not  obvious ?